# Python 2.7: List comprehension with "if-statement" runs very slowly

Tags: performance, python-2.7, if-statement, list-comprehension

I am having performance troubles with a script I wrote. It compares two images and calculates statistics. Basic principle is as follows:

I have two data sets (dataX and dataY), both of size 955*707 elements (675185 in total). In both data sets, there are missing values which are marked with "-999". So at first I get a list that marks the position of the missing values:

```
 del_items = []
 for i in range(sizeX):
     if dataX[i] == -999 or dataY[i] == -999:
         del_items.append(i)
```

This is done within the blink of an eye.
Now I want a subset of dataX and dataY of which those elements are removed that are -999 in either of the data sets (that's why I have the "or" connection above). I do this by list comprehension:

```
dataX = [x for i,x in enumerate(dataX) if i not in del_items]
dataY = [x for i,x in enumerate(dataY) if i not in del_items]
```

But this takes an incredible amount of time! I re-wrote the statements above to print out i and it takes about 2 minutes to get 100.000 items, so that would make 30 minutes for the whole image. That's way too long, considering how quick all other loops work in this script for data of the same size.

My assumption is that it takes so long, because it has to check if i is in del_items each and every time, whereas in the first loop it just has to verify if i is of a certain value.

Any ideas how I could speed up this process?
Thank you guys so much!

Comment: If you need to do these kind of tasks more often make sure to look into numpy. It is made for array operations: http://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial/#numpy - your code will be much faster, much cleaner and less error prone

Comment: I usually work with numpy as soon as it comes to matrices and stuff. But for one-dimensional arrays I kind of prefer the common python lists. There are some features in numpy that I don't have for the regular lists, but I didn't know it also works faster...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typical look-up in list problem - it has `O(n)` complexity. To achieve `O(1)` complexity, you need to convert your look-up list to set.

```
del_items = set()
for i in xrange(sizeX):
    if dataX[i] == -999 or dataY[i] == -999:
        del_items.add(i)
```

After that, `if i not in del_items` part of list comprehension will be performed in const time.

Comment: Oh wow! I changed thos few things and now the scripts runs within 5 seconds. Totally worth the effort of asking the question here. Thank you sooo much!

I think I might google what a set does and use it in other scripts as well. What's the difference between range and xrange? Why did you change that?

Comment: Since you are using Python2, `range` is not lazy - it returns list. Using `xrange` (lazy generation) is extra optimization of memory usage.